# How to change bottom navigation menu item to another fragment programmatically android kotlin?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I am using `BottomNavigationView` and `Navigation Component`.

Let's say I have 3 items in my menu, each of which leads to some `fragment`.

However, I needed to change some menu item to another `fragment`. How can i do this programmatically?

Menu XML code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/vector_home"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/newsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/vector_news"
    android:title="News" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/vector_settings"
    android:title="Settings" />
```

Setup menu in Activity code:

```
binding.apply {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

    val bottomNavViewLP = navView.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    bottomNavViewLP.behavior = BottomNavigationViewHideBehavior(this)

    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code to override bottomNavView's item clicks, so you can direct them to another fragment:

```
        navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.homeFragment -> {
                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                    navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)
                }
                R.id.newsFragment -> {
                    // Now news fragment item also navigates to settings
                    // And we remove it from backstack completely
                    navController.navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)
                    navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = true)
                }
                R.id.settingsFragment -> {
                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                    navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)
                }
            }
            true
        }
```

Comment: yes, this code does work, but there is a problem.

Navigation broke a little after adding this code. If earlier, in which of these fragments I was, my back button always led to startDestination (in my case, this is a fragment with news), now the navigation follows each other Example: A -> B -> C, Back button: C -> B -> A

Should be: A -> B -> C, Back button: C -> A

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should do what you want.